# Is there any way to trim data automatically

Tags: mysql

Lets I have a table named `myTable` in mysql with Three field

```
1. id int autoincrement
2. product_id varchar(20) not null
3. product_name varchar(200) not null
```

Now I want to keep data in `product_id` and `product_name` without white-space.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one way to do this will be to create a insert trigger on the table...can trim the values before inserting into the table ..

Comment: any specific reason to use trigger ?

Comment: whenever new records are inserted or any existing records are updated in the table ,it will ensure that only valid data (without white-space in your case) is entered into the table